# How to update texture in ThreeJS with loaded image data?

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

I'm looking for the best way to update a texture in threejs with data loaded from an image ?
loadTextture will create a new texture every time and i can't find a way to pass on an image object.

I've created the amount of textures needed with loadTexture, now every time i need to load a new image i just want to update my current textures with their data

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

This code should be of some help?

```
var image = document.createElement( 'img' );
var texture = new THREE.Texture( image );

image.onload = function () {

    texture.needsUpdate = true;

};

image.src = 'image.png';
```